# Global messages to a possibly uncreated WPF MVVM Window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, .net-3.5

I have a WPF window that implements the MVVM pattern. The window displays a list of available microphones that the user is supposed to select from. The selected microphone is then stored in our repository. All of this works fine, but **here is the problem**. The main window picks up when you plug a new microphone in, and displays a message saying something like: "A new device was plugged in, would you like to select it". If they click on this message, then the window for selection is supposed to pop up with the new device already selected. However, I am trying to keep the UI as a true MVVM pattern, with no code behind the xaml. Here are some options that I have thought up, but am not sure if any are the "correct" way to do this.

- Have a generic global action controller that will be passed into the ViewModel. The ViewModel can then subscribe to an event like `SelectionChangedEvent`

  - The problem with this is that the window (and therefore the view model) might not have been opened yet, so the message would be lost.
- Use the above option, but make the action controller always load the window first. This would solve the problem of the ViewModel not being available.
- Some other solution that I am not thinking of?

Comment: Are you using Prism?  It's not listed in the tags.  If you are, are you registering your pop-up view with the RegionManager?

Comment: @BigDaddy No, we are not using Prism. This is a WinForm to WPF conversion, so we have not rolled that in yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event Aggregator pattern is generally used to enable indirect communication between view models. There are a lot of good links on the topic. I like [Jeremy Miller's braindump](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/07/22/braindump-on-the-event-aggregator-pattern/) but it requires some background reading to fully understand.

The basic gist of the event aggregator is that it serves as a sort of Message Bus, anyone can register to be notified of a message, and anyone can publish the message to the EA. In your specific scenario, there would be 3 messages of note:

1. New Device Added
2. Request Device Selection
3. Device Selected

Your main window would publish the new device added message. (Or it can skip the publication and just fire the Request Device Selection message, one of the properties on the RDS message could be the default selection). Request Device Selection should cause the device selection dialog to display. And when the user selects the device it would fire the Device Selected message (which should contain the information about the selected device).

Whoever is interested in knowing that a new device has been selected would register for that event and respond accordingly.

Comment: So, you are basically saying my option 2 is what you would go with? The aggregator would have to make sure the window is loaded? This was where I was leaning, but was hoping for something better, as this requires a dependency that I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: No...the agreggator shouldn't do anything but send a message to subscribers. Someone else should subscribe for that message (perhaps the MainViewModel? or another actor in the system).